# How to convert digit to string with floating point?

Tags: javascript

How to convert number to string like this:

input: 120000.564
output: "120 000.56"

input: 12000.564
output: "12 000.56"

Comment: something like `.toLocaleString('en').replaceAll(',', ' ')` will do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different ways of printing an integer with a space as a thousands separators in JavaScript.
Here is one of the simplest ways is to use `String.prototype.replace()` function with the following arguments: `regular expression: (?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))` and `replacement value: '$1 '`

```
function formatNumber(num) {
  return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1 ')
}

console.log(formatNumber(120000.564));
```

Answer (score 1):

For formatting numbers, there is Intl.NumberFormat

```js
var n = 120000.564;
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('fr', { //space separator used in french locale
  style: 'decimal',
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
});
formatter.format(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .toString()
Example :

```
let input = 1.242724;
let output = input.toString();
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is vague and broad question
expect same kind of answer too
 you need to do 2 step

1. make your number upto 2 digit as currency (Auxiliary step if you needed).

   parseFloat(120000.564,1).toFixed(2);
2. just giving you another function to use it [credits][1] refer for some new requirements.

```js
function formatMoney(amount, decimalCount = 2, decimal = ".", thousands = " ") {
  try {
    decimalCount = Math.abs(decimalCount);
    decimalCount = isNaN(decimalCount) ? 2 : decimalCount;

    const negativeSign = amount < 0 ? "-" : "";

    let i = parseInt(amount = Math.abs(Number(amount) || 0).toFixed(decimalCount)).toString();
    let j = (i.length > 3) ? i.length % 3 : 0;

    return negativeSign + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + thousands : '') + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + thousands) + (decimalCount ? decimal + Math.abs(amount - i).toFixed(decimalCount).slice(2) : "");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
};
```

Comment: @grzegoroz T why did you removed credits that was helpful link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-to-format-numbers-as-currency-string

Comment: I think I deleted too much :)